# Python: Shutdown PC without login

Tags: python, linux

I'm trying to:

1. boot Linux PC (from BIOS automatic on)
2. execute Python script (crontab)
3. shutdown PC (last code line Python script)

No problem for 1-2. Yet for #3, I can't shut the PC down:

```
import os

os.system("shutdown -h now")
```

No error in `/var/log/syslog`.

Can you help me?

Comment: which user is the cron task running under and does he have sufficient rights to run `shutdown -h now`?

Comment: Does Python throw any errors/messages when running manually?

Comment: How can I see which user is the cron task running?

Comment: No error or message when running manually (shutdown ok)

Comment: Well, you can just add `shutdown -h now` to crontab directly and see if it works from there. If it does, then you have a Python problem to investigate, and if it doesn't, you have a cron, shutdown or permission problem to investigate.